# Uninstalling OpenKinect Driver?

Tags: kinect

I've tried to uninstall the OpenKinect drivers but was unable to do so. What is the proper way to uninstall the drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove them through the Uninstall Programs window in the Control Panel. If not, you could try going through the device manager and uninstalling anything related to the Kinect. If you're switching over to the official SDK, be aware that there are some limitations on using multiple Kinects at the same time which may not have been present with the OpenKinect stuff.

Comment: I've tried to remove everything from Device Manager but when I re-scan for hardware changes it automatically gets installed, why is that so?

Comment: Is the Kinect still plugged in when you do the scan?

Answer (score 0):

Normally deleting the driver in the device manager should work and it shouldn't matter if the Kinect is plugged in or not. You can also look up the driver name in the device manager and remove it manually from the system32 folder.